# Maven maven-surefire-plugin not all tests are running

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, maven-surefire-plugin

for some reason when i run Maven test using version `2.20` of `maven-surefire-plugin` My Java Integration Tests And Unit Tests are executing. When I use `2.22.1` of `maven-surefire-plugin` it runs only Mock and Smoke tests. What can be the solution to run all tests at once?

pom.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>weatherProject</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.1</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

I tried using multiple version but it didn't help. Tried using newest version of `maven-surefire-plugin`

Comment: What version of JUnit are the tests running against? I'm guessing it's not consistent between the mock/smoke tests and the rest?

Comment: junit-jupiter 5.9.1

Comment: Are you sure about that? That sounds like the version of the junit library, not the junit version of the tests. JUnit 3/4/5 tests are declared differently (i.e. name vs annotation).

Comment: If you are really using JUnit Jupiter (which based on the pom file you have posted here does not give an evidence of that) you have to use most recent version of maven-surefire-plugin (3.0.0-M7 at the moment)... If you use other junit framework versions like JUnit 4.X or TestNG you have to define the dependencies in an appropriate way (I would suggest to take a look at this YT video for JUnit Jupiter https://youtu.be/NVvMzy0Lin0)

Comment: Checked, i have JUnit 4.11-beta-1

Comment: v2.20 had no (official) support for junit5 (my assumption: since v2.22) proofs here: http://archive.apache.org/dist/maven/surefire/ ... But still strange! And why not 3.0.0.M7!?

Comment: First using an out of date version of JUnit 4 also using JUnit 4 while JUnit Jupiter (aka Junit 5 is there for a long time) you should go with JUnit Jupiter instead ....

Comment: I tried using maven-surefire-plugin version 3.0.0-M7 but still it's running only 2 of 4 tests

Comment: The first version of maven-surefire-plugin which supports JUnit 5 is version 2.22.2 (See https://maven.apache.org/surefire-archives/surefire-2.22.2/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/junit-platform.html)

Comment: Please show your test source code at best would be a github project ...

Comment: GitHub project
https://github.com/AlenSiilivask/ICD0004

Comment: Created a Pull request for your project and cleaned up a lot of things... take a deeper look into it...if you have further question don't hesitate to contact me.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is your problem?

Directly from the Surefire Plugin website, [Upgrade Check for JUnit 4.x](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/junit.html#upgrade-check-for-junit-4-x)

> As of Surefire version 2.7, the algorithm for choosing which tests to run has changed. From 2.7 and on, only valid JUnit tests are run for all versions of JUnit, where older versions of the plugin would also run invalid tests that satisfied the naming convention.

> When upgrading from a Surefire version prior to 2.7, the build can be run with the flag `-Dsurefire.junit4.upgradecheck`. This will perform a check and notify you of any invalid tests that will not be run with this version of Surefire (and the build fails). This is only meant to be used as a tool when upgrading to check that all expected tests will be run. It is a transitional feature that will be removed in a future version of surefire.